# How can I allow only a specific user role to update an attribute to a specific value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Afternoon, got a bit of an issue I am not sure how to resolve.

I am trying to setup some rules that allows only certain types of user roles to update the status attribute on a model to a certain status.

So I looked into doing this with pundit as it seems to be an authorisation issue, however one problem with that is you cannot pass the params to the pundit policy which I would need access too (so I can see what attribute they are trying to change to), and it seems that its bad practise to pass params to a pundit policy.

The next option was to make it a callback in the model, however the problem here is I don’t have access to the current_user inside the callback and again it seems its bad practise to add the current_user helper into a model.

So I am left with perhaps doing it in the controller? Again does not seem the right place for it?

An example to make it a little easier to understand:

I want to allow a User with the role of admin to be allowed to change the status of a post to "resolved", no one else is allowed to change the status to "resolved"

Comment: You can pass current_user to a local variable and do it at the model. This is one approach that makes sense rather than the controller level.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
create a instance method in User model like bellow,

```
def is_admin?
  self.has_role(:admin)   # if you are using rolify 
      ---OR---
  self.status == "admin"  # if you have status attribute in your user table
end
```

Then call this method on current_user in edit/update method of post controller. to check current_user is admin or not